# How to recover streaming data even if the connection lost with Python client Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, restful-url

I stream RESTful API data from https://www.n2yo.com/api/ which for tracking satellite positions. 
I use python client with Elasticsearch. I save the streamed data to ES every 10 seconds and visualized by Kibana. My ES vesrion is 6.4.3

My code is:

```
URL = "https://www.n2yo.com/rest/v1/satellite/positions/25544/41.702/-76.014/0/2/&apiKey= your key"



es = Elasticsearch('http://ip:port',timeout=600)

settings = { "settings": {
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                  'number_of_replicas':0
                 },
      "mappings" : { 
           "document" : {
                "properties":{
                    "geo": {
                       "type": "geo_point"
                            }
                          }
                        } 
                     } 
                  }
try:
 es.indices.create(index = "spacestation", body=settings)
except RequestError as es1:
 print('Index already exists!!')
 sys.exit(1)

def collect_data():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 
  del data['positions'][1]
  new_data = {'geo':{'lat':data['positions'][0]['satlatitude'],
               'lon':data['positions'][0]['satlongitude']}, 
                'satname': data['info']['satname'], 'satid': data['info']['satid'], 
                  'timestamp':datetime.fromtimestamp(data['positions'][0]['timestamp']).isoformat()        
              }

  es.index(index='spacestation', doc_type='document', body=new_data)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(collect_data)

while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

My question is: Yesterday I lost the connection. The error is as below,

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.n2yo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/v1/satellite/positions/25544/41.702/-76.014/0/2/&apiKey= (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))

When I re-run my code, I can't because the index is already exist. If I delete the index I will lost my data which already in ES. What I can do? I need to keep my saved data and I need to run the job from now. Any solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the index only if you receive the data from n2yo.com . you should use the function `es.indices.exists` .Then you make your function `collect_data` recursive in case of failure. Try:

```
 URL = "https://www.n2yo.com/rest/v1/satellite/positions/25544/41.702/-76.014/0/2/&apiKey= your key"



es = Elasticsearch('http://ip:port',timeout=600)

def create_index()

    if not es.indices.exists(index = "spacestation"):

        settings = { "settings": {
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                  'number_of_replicas':0
                 },
      "mappings" : { 
           "document" : {
                "properties":{
                    "geo": {
                       "type": "geo_point"
                            }
                          }
                        } 
                     } 
                  }
          es.indices.create(index = "spacestation", body=settings)
    else:
        print('Index already exists!!')
        

def collect_data():
  try:
      data = requests.get(url = URL).json()
      create_index() 
      del data['positions'][1]
      new_data = {'geo':{'lat':data['positions'][0]['satlatitude'],
               'lon':data['positions'][0]['satlongitude']}, 
                'satname': data['info']['satname'], 'satid': data['info']['satid'], 
                  'timestamp':datetime.fromtimestamp(data['positions'][0]['timestamp']).isoformat()        
              }

      es.index(index='spacestation', doc_type='document', body=new_data)
    except ConnectionError:
        collect_data()

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(collect_data)

while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try. But  could you please tell me what will happen in "except" ? I understood that "try" is to insert data to my index.

Comment: if the function collect_dat ends for an error the except statement capture any error inside it and relauch the same function. A function that call itself is called recursive. So inasmuch for this use case the only possible errors of the function collect_data could be the connection errors -to ny2yo or to es - you will rerun the same function because you expect that the connection error is temporary and do not depend from your configurations that is ok

Comment: if in collect_data function could be other errors - for example on this line: del data['positions'][1] - you should replace except: with except ConnectionError:

Comment: I tried according to you, but gave me an error when  I put "settings" under "if not". So I put  settings right after the function. But got error with "if not" .  if not es.indices.exists(index = "spacestation"):
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: an indentation should have 4 spaces, not a tab. The interpreter found that you have used both 4 spaces and tabs in your code for the indentation. Please use only 4 spaces. If you use an IDE as Pycharm you could resolve it very quickly

Comment: Yes you're correct had a indentation mistake.. Your code is working, But even the index is already exist program is running , it show the message "index is already exist" but keep running ( streaming data). But if index is there program should be stop, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216060/discussion-between-lupanoide-and-user).